# How to get referrer url on WP rest api

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

Wordpress developers.
I have a problem with Wordpress Rest API.
I want to get the referrer host(url, domain) that call wp rest api on Rest server side.
For example, domainA.com send request using wp_remote_request('domainB.com/wp-json/myurl') and I want to get domainA.com.
How can I get it on wordpress rest api side?
using which hook?
Can I get it on "rest_api_init" hook or on its callback function?

```
add_action( 'rest_api_init', array( $this, 'plugin_rest_api_endpoint' ) );

public function plugin_rest_api_endpoint( $server ){

    register_rest_route( 'link_manager', '/get_links', array(
        'methods' => 'GET',
        'callback' =>  array($this, 'plugin_process_client_request'),
    ) );
    //Get domainA.com from here.
}
```

or

```
public function plugin_process_client_request($data){
    //Get domainA.com from here
}
```

Comment: I assume browsers are not involved here due to wp_remote_request so you should not expect referrer field in request. Good practice would be giving away different credentials to different "partners" which would become part of request and would allow you to recognize "visitor".